# How can I "clear line/paragraph" as opposed to add a line/paragraph break?

Tags: indentation, line-spacing

I have this command, call it `\foo` which I want to make sure will result in text written at the beginning of the paragraph. So, if you write:

```
Quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog etc. etc.
... over the lazy dog.

\foo
```

I want `\foo` to do the equivalent of `\noindent`; but if you write:

```
Quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog etc. etc.
... over the lazy dog. \foo

More text here
```

I want `\foo` to be on a separate paragraph than the Quick brown fox text, as though my source were:

```
Quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog etc. etc.
... over the lazy dog. 

\noindent \foo

More text here
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `\foo` to start a new, unindented paragraph. The solution is to just use `\par\noindent`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\foo{\par\noindent[This is foo!]}

\begin{document}

Quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog etc. etc.
... over the lazy dog.

\foo

Quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog etc. etc.
... over the lazy dog. \foo

More text here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, `\par` is what I was missing, yes. Thank you.